# Why 1 cm is 1 km in my map?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, scale, resolution

I have this map in ArcMap ([you can download my map document from here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=EF94C04C3A9AAD3!187&authkey=!AGODqKuxsaDIhAo&ithint=file%2Cmxd)), and I don't know why, but if I set the scale to 1:1, I can see my whole city.

When I used the measure tool, I found out that whats 1 cm in my map, should be 1 km.

I want to make buffers, but when I set the buffer to, like, 8 meters, the circles are covering the whole map, because they are 8000 kilometers.

I am an absolute noob in GIS software and I just started using ArcMap some days ago.

I'm using ArcMap 10.2.2.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution! I should use the Define Projection tool to use different coordinate system (WGS), and repeated it for every layer, and now it's WORKING!

Answer (score 1):

Go to Data Frame Properties and under General change your Map units to meters.

Comment: I can't change the Map units, it's grayed out.

Comment: I can only change the Display units there.

Comment: What coordinate system are you in? Are you in the right coordinate system for what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: These are the information under the "current coordinate system" in the Data Frame Properties window:
HD_1972_Egyseges_Orszagos_Vetuleti
Authority: Custom

Projection: Hotine_Oblique_Mercator_Azimuth_Center
False_Easting: 650000,0
False_Northing: 200000,0
Scale_Factor: 0,99993
Azimuth: 90,0
Longitude_Of_Center: 19,048571778
Latitude_Of_Center: 47,14439372222
Linear Unit: Meter (1,0)

Geographic Coordinate System: GCS_Hungarian_1972
Angular Unit: Degree (0,0174532925199433)
Prime Meridian: Greenwich (0,0)
Datum: D_Hungarian_1972
  Spheroid: GRS_1967

Comment: And I don't know what coordinate system should I use, I just want the Buffer thing to work.